# How to make a dynamic textbox name in PHP

Tags: php

```
`$row_data .='<input type="textbox"  name="left + $i" />'; `
```

`$pst[] = $_POST['left'];`
 i++;

how to create dynamic textbox and store it in array

Comment: Use array instead of indexing names, `name="left[]"`. After submitting all data will be in `$_POST['left']`, or `$_GET['left']` as array.

Comment: You see how you're using `.` to concatenate strings together? Do that.

Answer (score 1):

Variables don't expand in single-quoted strings:

```
'<input type="textbox"  name="left + $i" />'
```

So if you really *want* to do this, you could make it double-quoted and use escape characters for the inner double-quotes, though I prefer concatenation in cases like this:

```
'<input type="textbox"  name="left' . $i . '" />'
```

Then you'd get the values from the `$_POST` array with the same technique:

```
$someVariable = $_POST['name' . $i];
```

It would be your responsibility to track the values of `$i` between rendering the form and receiving the form values.

**However**, consider an alternate approach entirely:

```
'<input type="textbox"  name="left[]" />'
```

What this does is submit *all* of the values in the `name="left[]"` elements *as an array* to the server.  So `$_POST['left']` would contain an array instead of a single value.

Comment: $row_data .='<input type="textbox"  name="left' . $i . '" />';
 $pst[] = $_POST['left'];
 if(count($pst)!=0)
  { do someting}
am i correct sir??

Comment: @DummyMail: That looks like a mix of both approaches, so no.  (That also doesn't look to me like how one declares an array in PHP, that's how one *adds* to an *existing* array variable.)  Which approach do you want?  The dynamic `name` value or the array of values?

Comment: dynamic name value.. i want to store these inputs to database

Comment: @DummyMail: Well, *both* approaches allow you to store your data in a database.  (Or, more accurately, neither approach *prevents* you from storing data in a database.  Because why would they?  This has nothing to do with a database.)  If you *really* want to use the dynamic `name` value then simply use the concatenation suggested in the first part of this answer.  I've updated the answer to include example usage after submitting the form.

Comment: Thankyou so much. i really appreciate:

Comment: $row_data .='<input type="textbox"  name="left' . $i . '" />';
               $qrys = "UPDATE testone SET firstname='" .  $_POST['left' . 2] . "' WHERE id=3";
           mysqli_query($con, $qrys)
is this correct? because its not working

Comment: @DummyMail: Define "not working".  In what specific way does it fail?  What is the resulting HTML `<input>` element?  Is it posted to the server?  What's in the `$_POST` array at that time?  What is your resulting SQL query?  (Note: Your code is *wide open* to SQL injection, so you could be trying to executing anything.)  Does the query fail?  What's the error form MySQL?  "It's not working" doesn't describe the problem in any meaningful way.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. it is not giving any error. just the value is not getting into the database.
$qrys = "UPDATE testone SET firstname='" .  $_POST['left' . $i] . "' WHERE id='".$i."'";
                 if (mysqli_query($con, $qrys)) {
      echo "Record updated successfully";
            } 
   else {
      echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }

Comment: @DummyMail: Then you need to do some debugging.  The information present doesn't demonstrate the problem.  Again, your code is wide open to SQL injection, so there's no telling what you're actually trying to execute.  Use your browser's debugging tools to see if the POST request contains the information you expect it to.  Add various `echo` and/or `var_dump()` statements to your PHP code to see the runtime values of the variables you're using and the SQL code you're building.  Find information about the problem.

Comment: i tested.
 name="left' . $i . '"
is not taking any value.
means
'".$_POST['left'.$x]."'   have no value inside it
https://pastebin.com/CXdMXYgF
code in above link
line no 181 and 273

Comment: @DummyMail: In line 181 what is the *actual HTML* that gets emitted to the browser?  In line 273 what is the *actual key/value* being requested from the POST data?  A casual glance suggests that you're starting one array at `0` and another at `1`.  Debug and see what you're actually doing, rather than just making assumptions and saying "it doesn't work".

Comment: i am literally not able to find the solution. are you on skype so that i can share my problem. and i really appreciate time you given me sir

Comment: @DummyMail: I'm afraid you're misunderstanding how the Stack Overflow community works.  We don't offer personal tutoring services.  You're going to have to specifically identify the nature of the problem.  This would be a good time to look up some tutorials and examples of how to debug PHP code, as well as how to use your browser's debugging tools.  We can offer answers based on the information you provide, but we can't debug your code on your computer for you.  You have to be able to do that.

Comment: ok sir.i am trying. but still thank you so much for time you given